# Bing Map Silverlight control can't pan when user clicks on UIElement (Tunnelling Bubbling)

Tags: silverlight, mouseevent, bing-maps, uielement

I am using the Silverlight Bing Maps control in an application. There is a canvas hosted over the map with various UIElements.

A problem I am currently observing is the map mouse-down pans the map correctly, unless the mouse-down originates on a `UIElement` (Element in question is a MapPolyLine).

UIElements are added to the map with the following code

```
        var outlineBottom = new MapPolyline {
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(bottomColor),
            StrokeThickness = width * TrailBottomLineWidthMultiplier,
            Opacity = 1, //opacity,
            StrokeMiterLimit = 1,
            Locations = locations
        };
```

This results in a poly line of thickness ~5px being added to the map. When the user mouse-downs on the map but the mouse pointer is over the line, it cannot be panned.

How can I stop the MapPolyline above swallowing mouse events so the map can be panned?

Comment: Have you tried UIElement.IsHitTestVisible ?

Comment: OK - I'll add as an answer - earn my points ;-)

Comment: Hmm no change. SilverlightSpy reporting that the MapPolyLine has IsHitTestVisible=true even after programmatically setting it to false. MapPolyLine also has an inner PolyLine which has IsHitTestvisible=True (Im not sure if I can access it from the API)

Comment: @ColinE My mistake, it does work, was testing the wrong element. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `UIElement.IsHitTestVisible = false` on your `MapPolyline`.